# If condition in background.js not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made a little extension to block images on a website which I can turn on and off via the popup. I got the everything working except the part where it checks if it should block the images or not. This is what I got at the moment:

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Name",
    "description": "Description",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {  "256": "256icon.png",
                "128": "128icon.png",
                "64": "64icon.png",
                "48": "48icon.png",
                "32": "32icon.png",
                "16": "16icon.png" },

    "browser_action": {
       "default_title": "Name",
       "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": true
    },

    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "webNavigation",
        "management",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "*://static2.gamekit.com/upload/*" 
    ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <div class="PopUp" id="PopUp">
        <div class="onoffswitch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    'use strict';
    var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    document.getElementById("myonoffswitch").checked = bg.onoffstate;
}); //gets checkbox state from background.js and applies it

function updatecheck() { //onclick function of the checkbox
    'use strict';
//puts checkbox state in var (checkstate)
    var checkstate = document.getElementById("myonoffswitch").checked;
//sends checkbox state to background.js
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({onoffstate: checkstate}, function (response) {
        console.log(response.bg_onoffstate); //response from background.js
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').addEventListener('click', updatecheck);
}); //adds onclick event to checkbox
```

background.js

```
var onoffstate;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        'use strict';
        onoffstate = request.onoffstate; //puts checkbox state from popup.js into var
        sendResponse({bg_onoffstate: onoffstate}); //debug response
    }
);


if (onoffstate === true) { //check if checkbox is checked
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function (details) {
            'use strict';
            return {cancel: true};
        },
        {urls: ["*://static2.gamekit.com/upload/*"]},
        ["blocking"] //blocks images
    );
}
```

(sorry for messy code)

When loading the popup.html it pulls the saved state(true/false) from the background.js and applies it to the checkbox. When checking the (un)checkbox in the popup.html it sends its state to the background.js. The saved state in the background.js then determinants if the images should be blocked or not. And this is where it doesn't work right. The code that blocks the images itself works perfectly by itself. But when I put it inside the `if` function it won't trigger. I tried putting other stuff in it to see if it would execute it but it didn't.

I was looking if I had a typo somewhere but didn't find anything. JSLint also doesn't show anything.

I hope someone can find out what's wrong.

Link to files for easier access: [**Here**](http://filebin.ca/3CpplJdVqoe2)

Comment: It looks like you're hitting your conditional before your listener gets the state. Try initializing  var onoffstate to a string and then print the print the var in your if conditional block to see if it was modified.

Comment: Move the if inside the evet listener! Or wrap it inside a function and call the function from within the event listener!

Comment: **Don't** move the `if` condition inside the handler. This will bind the `onBeforeRequest` handler multiple times and this is a very bad practice.

Comment: Chrome API is asynchronous so the variable is not yet defined when you check it, see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add your if condition inside `onMessage` event handler (As suggested in the comments). This will bind `onBeforeRequest` event handler multiple times.

**Solution:** Remove your condition and just return the state inside `onBeforeRequest` handler.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function (details) {
        'use strict';
          return {cancel: onoffstate};
    },
    {urls: ["*://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/*"]},
    ["blocking"] //blocks images
);
```